# css can not find background image in my folders

Tags: css, background-image

I am allowing users to choose their theme folder /views/theme/images/ theme can be chosen by the user. The css is in the theme folder along with the image folder.

```
.header {
    float:left;
    height:100px;
    width:100%;
    background-image: (/images/bg-nav.png);
}
```

and I have tried lots of different image paths in the background image but it's not showing I have tried /views/default/images/bg-nav.png, I've added dots, forward slashes etc.

The image does exist in the following folder: /views/default/images/bg-nav.png can someone help me to display and find my image :/

Here's my html css include

```
<link href="/views/<?php echo $system->theme(); ?>/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

It is including fine the stylesheet is working

Comment: if your image is `/views/default/images/bg-nav.png`, then WHY are you using `/images/bg-nav.php`?

Comment: a tip open pic and file in two browser window and then check the url and if u can post here

Comment: I don't want to include the /default/ path as that can be changed via the theme selector. so it could be default or customtheme etc

Comment: I want to grab the image without using the theme name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example code above:

```
background-image: (/images/bg-nav.png);
```

Should be:

```
background-image: url('/images/bg-nav.png');
```

You are missing the `url`. Check the [syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).

Comment: will accept as best answer in 8 minutes. Thank you.